# Cannot find settings for repository on Github

Tags: git, github, github-webhook

I am trying to do the following [Automatic Pull on Server](https://www.jobsity.com/blog/automatic-pull-server) by using webhooks.

The problem is that I cannot find settings in my repository.
Did github.com removed it? Can anyone give me a helping hand on solving this mystery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was just a collaborator of the repository.
You need to be the owner of the repo to see the settings.